# How to calculate $\nabla_x x^\top x$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Various resources claim

$
\nabla_x x^\top x = 2x
$
.

I only know

$
\nabla_X f(X)  = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{11}} & \cdots  & \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{1m}}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{n1}} & \cdots  & \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{nm}} 
\end{bmatrix}
$

How do I use the above rule to get $\nabla_x x^\top x = 2x$?

Hint: Based on my understand, even if a question look like homework, if OP explained his point of view and his own efforts to understand, and he only asks for confirmation / rejection / details, the question should be on topic.

I tried the following, but cannot find the answer.

$
\begin{align*}
\nabla_Z f(Z) =& \nabla_Z\begin{bmatrix}
z_{11} & \cdots  & z_{1m}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
z_{n1} & \cdots  &z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
z_{11} & \cdots  & z_{1m}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
z_{n1} & \cdots  &z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
 =& \nabla_Z\begin{bmatrix}
z_{11} & \cdots  & z_{n1}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
z_{1m} & \cdots  &z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z_{11} & \cdots  & z_{1m}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
z_{n1} & \cdots  &z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix} \notag \\ 
 =& \nabla_Z\begin{bmatrix}
z_{11}z_{11}+z_{21}z_{21}+\cdots +z_{n1}z_{n1} & \cdots  & z_{11}z_{1m}+z_{21}z_{2m}+\cdots +z_{n1}z_{nm}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
z_{1m}z_{11}+z_{2m}z_{21}+\cdots +z_{nm}z_{n1} & \cdots  & z_{1m}z_{1m}+z_{2m}z_{2m}+\cdots +z_{nm}z_{nm}
\end{bmatrix} \notag \\ 
 =& \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_{11}} z_{11}z_{11}+z_{21}z_{21}+\cdots +z_{n1}z_{n1} & \cdots  & \frac{\partial}{\partial z_{1m}}z_{11}z_{1m}+z_{21}z_{2m}+\cdots +z_{n1}z_{nm}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_{n1}}z_{1m}z_{11}+z_{2m}z_{21}+\cdots +z_{nm}z_{n1} & \cdots  & \frac{\partial}{\partial z_{nm}}z_{1m}z_{1m}+z_{2m}z_{2m}+\cdots +z_{nm}z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix} \notag \\
= & \begin{bmatrix}
2z_{11} & z_{11} & \cdots  & z_{11}\\ 
        & 2z_{22} \\
\vdots  & \\ 
z_{nm} & z_{nm} & \cdots  & 2z_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix} \notag
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Hint: write, as a sum, the product $x^T x$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I wrote it to the sum. Can you check if it's correct?

Comment: You made the same mistake as in the other post. $x^Tx$ is a scalar.

Comment: $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$By the way, in general for a constant square matrix $A$ (of compatible size to multiply with $\x$), there is the [general formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709686/gradient-of-xtax) $$\color{blue}{\nabla_{\x}\left(\x^T A\x\right) =\left(A + A^T\right)\x}.$$ Your example is with $A=I$ (identity matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Based on definition of gradient, gradient is only applicable to function f if the result of f is real number.

Then, since we assume $\nabla_x x^\top x = 2x$ is valid, x must be a vector, or a N-by-1 matrix. Next, we treat x as a matrix because we are using matrix operations, eg. transpose and matrix multiplication.

$$f(x)=x^\top x= x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$$

Also, based on the definition, the matrix size of $\nabla_x f(x)$ is the same as the size of x.

Now we can apply definition 1 in OP's question to $x^\top x$.

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla_x x^\top x  =& \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x^\top x}{\partial x_{1}} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\frac{\partial  x^\top x}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{bmatrix} \\ 
 =& \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{\partial x_{1}} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\frac{\partial  x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
 =& \begin{bmatrix}
2x_1 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
2x_n
\end{bmatrix} \\
=& 2 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
x_n
\end{bmatrix} \\
=& 2x
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\boldsymbol x^T\boldsymbol x=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Then

$$\nabla_{\boldsymbol x}(\boldsymbol x^T\boldsymbol x)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2+z^2),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2+z^2),\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\right)=(2x,2y,2z).$$