# Gradient of $a'Xa$ not equal to $2Xa$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

Let's say

$$a'Xa = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

By using common differentiation rules, we have:

$$\frac{\partial a'Xa}{\partial a} = 2Xa=
\begin{bmatrix}
    2a_1+4a_2 \\
    6a_1 +8a_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

However, as $a'Xa$ can also be expressed as

$$a_1^2+5a_1a_2+4a_2^2$$

when we differentiate it w.r.t. $a$, we'll get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    2a_1+5a_2 \\
    5a_1 +8a_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Any ideas why these two results are different? Thanks so much!

Comment: Which “common differentiation rule” justifies your first version?

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative formula is only valid when the matrix is symmetric. Otherwise, it is
$$2X_s a=Xa+X^t a$$
Where $X_s$ is the symmetric part of $X$, i.e.
$$X_s=\frac{X+X^t}{2}$$
This happens, because in the symmetric+antisymmetric part decomposition of a matrix, we have that
$$a^tXa=a^t(X_s+X_a)a=a^tX_sa+a^tX_aa=a^tX_sa$$
Where the antisymmetric part is
$$X_a=\frac{X-X^t}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need the matrix $X$ to be symmetric for your result to hold. The general result is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (a' Xa) = \left(X + X'\right)a.$$ See the answers here for example for proofs: [Gradient of $x^{T}Ax$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709686/gradient-of-xtax).